# Excel can't find path - Macro - Run Time Error 76

Tags: excel, vba, path, runtime-error

I needed to create userform for Project Tracker Sheet.
I created a userform in excel and assigned the macro created

**Code Inside UserForm for save:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Set ws = Worksheets("Projects")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim textBoxes As Variant
    textBoxes = Array(TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5, TextBox6, TextBox7, TextBox8, TextBox9, TextBox10, TextBox11, TextBox12, TextBox13, TextBox14, TextBox15, TextBox16, TextBox17, txtback, txtperson, txtstorage, txtwork, txtaccess, txtdoc, txtdoclink, txtadd)
    For i = 0 To UBound(textBoxes)
        ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, i + 4).Value = textBoxes(i).Value
    Next i
    ' Clear TextBox values
    For i = 0 To UBound(textBoxes)
        textBoxes(i).Value = ""
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Code to Clear Data Entered:**

```
 Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
        Unload Me
        UserForm1.Show
    End Sub
```

**Close UserForm:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

**Code to open image on initializing:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim imgPath As String
    imgPath = "C:\Users\Nair.Ha\Downloads\logo.gif"
    Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(imgPath)
    Me.Image1.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeStretch ' Adjust the PictureSizeMode as desired
End Sub
```

**Code to open userform:**

```
Sub GraphicClick()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

to one graphic visual. Now the macro is running in my computer properly.

Now I put the macro enabled Excel workbook to Sharepoint so my team members can use it.

But when they try to open the Excel using option Open Excel in Desktop, they aren't able to run the macro.
They're getting **Runtime error 76: Path not found**.

I want the macro to run in all PC's.

I believe the problem is the path is saved in my pc even after uploading the file to sharepoint. I can't find the way to change the path.

Do I need to export the Userform file (.frm) to the same Sharepoint site and then try to import it from there?

Please help me I'm confused.

Comment: Where is the code that uses the path? I do not see it in your question. When the error happens, click DEBUG and it will show you the part of the code you need to find.

Comment: Yeah I forgot about that. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Try it like this: `"C:\Users\" & Environ$("UserName") & "\Downloads\logo.gif"` - this assumes everyone has that file on their computer in the same place.

Comment: If that's the only problem you have, I would say to just remove the logo.gif image altogether. It's really not worth the effort.

Comment: Or have it in Sharepoint if it is a requirement, idk if it would have difficulties loading.

Comment: Ok, thank you all for your help. Will try to change the image location.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I just removed the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save logo.gif file next to the excel file and make this change to code

From

```
imgPath = "C:\Users\Nair.Ha\Downloads\logo.gif"
```

To

```
imgPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\logo.gif"
```

Comment: So, I have to save the image in my sharepoint and then do this, right?